# Margin-top and Margin-bottom not applying to inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to move my spinner div upwards. Whether it's negative or positive values to move the circle to have it center on the `img`. It works on my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/KXOZjE) but not on my [Webpage](https://mydietgoal.com/features/). I read about some possible solutions like adding `display: inline-block` / `display: block` and `overflow: hidden` but they don't seem to work with my code. Why would code that works on Codepen not work on my web page?

```css
.bodyImage1 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -10%;
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

/*Advance animation*/

.connector3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 360px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  animation: drawConnector 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0083f5 15%, #f57300 105%);
}

.spinner1 {
  align-items: center;
  border: .3em solid transparent;
  border-top: .3em solid #f57300;
  border-right: .3em solid #f57300;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.spinnerOut {
  animation: spinnerOne 3s linear infinite;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-left: 150%;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.spinnerMid {
  animation: spinnerOne 5s linear infinite;
  height: 2.4em;
  width: 2.4em;
}

.spinnerInn {
  animation: spinnerOne 5s linear infinite;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 1.8em;
}

@keyframes spinnerOne {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="connector3 block-anim invis">
  <div class="spinner1 spinnerOut invis">
    <div class="spinner1 spinnerMid">
      <div class="spinner1 spinnerInn"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably some other styles override yours. check in web inspector, what the actual styles are applied to your elements. Or you can add `!important` to the margin values, just to check if there is some other styles override yours.

Comment: I don't see the styles you've declared on CodePen in the styles I see declared on your production site, which leads me to believe that this is not a *specificity* issue - otherwise we would see those styles on your production site as well, when inspecting the element in question, only crossed-out, or *over-qualified*. So, **have you ruled out caching?** And if so, how are you sure that you have? The browser could be requesting a cached version of the stylesheet (from the server), you are applying your styles in; which would mean that you are not seeing the latest updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a margin-top: important on the spinner on your site. Changing it moves the spinner around.

Site.css, prettified, line 27301

```
.spinnerOut {
    animation: spinnerOne 3s linear infinite;
    margin-top: -225px !important;
    margin-left: 150%;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
}
```

[image]

[image]